# An algorithm with time complexity O(nlogr) to find first kj (1 ≤ j ≤ r) smallest numbers in a set S

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

Considering the multiple select problem. There is a set S which has n elements. And there is another set K which has r numbers of k1, k2, ... kr. Please find the first k1, k2, ... kr small numbers in the set S.

For example,K = {2,7,9,50}, that is, from the n elements, you need to find the 2nd, 7th, 9th, 50th smallest elements.

The ordinary solution is to run SELECT algorithm for each kj (1 ≤ j ≤ r) to find the first kj small element, then the total time complexity is Θ(r⋅n), please give an algorithm with time complexity O(nlogr) to solve this problem.

Prove the time complexity is O(nlogr).

---

It's my 1st time to use StackOverflow.

My first thought was to modify the SELECT algorithm by adding a tag to mark if A[i] (A[i] is an element of set S) has been confirmed at its location.

For example, in the former access, I have confirmed A[5] and A[18] (then A[5] is the 5th smallest number, A[18] is the 19th smallest number, and numbers between A[5] and A[18] are just between index 5 and index 18).

If I need to find the 9th smllest number now. I just need to SELECT (A, 9, 5, 18) instead of SELECT(A, 9, 1, n).

Am I right? I don't how to calculate the time complexity under this complex circumstance.

Comment: no offense but this sounds like you just pasted a school assignment here, did you try something before typing this? maybe edit the post with some tough of your own how this could be solved to show you at least tried before expecting someone else to do all the work for you

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. It's my 1st time to use StackOverflow. My first thought was to modify the SELECT algorithm by adding a tag to mark if A[i] (A[i] is an element of set S) has been confirmed at its location. For example, in the former access, I have confirmed A[5] and A[18] (then A[5] is the 5th smallest number, A[18] is the 19th smallest number, and numbers between A[5] and A[18] are just between index 5 and index 18). If I need to find the 9th smllest number now. I just need to sort (A, 9, 5, 18) instead of sort(A, 9, 1, n).

Comment: well yeah assuming both sets are sorted, to get the logr time complexity you will prolly have to do a divide et impera  (divide and rule (?) in english) algorithm, the simple binary search gets you the logarithmic time complexity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), think about our given complexity requirment you worst case needs to be for n * logr so you can assuime you have to at least go trough set S linear - hope that helps you, also yeah of course with the sorted array you can assume that everything below the already checked range is lower like you already pointed out

Comment: Hint, if you see log(sizeofsomearray) in the required complexity this probably means you should try to divide that array in half and solve the problem for each half.

Comment: Unluckly the two sets are not sorted. And I think the binary search may not be suitable here.

Comment: Well, you know the SELECT algorithm looks like the QUICKSORT, it uses recursion. Here log(size of some array) comes from recursion instead of binary search.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

In the discussion below, `k` is the length of the array `K`, and `s` is the length of the array `S`.

1. Scan `K` to get the maximum number. Call this `r`. Complexity: O(k).
2. Call Quickselect on `S` to select the `r` smallest numbers. Complexity: O(s).
3. Build a binary min heap from the result of #2. Call this heap `rSmallest`. Complexity: O(r)
4. Create a set from `K`. Basically, a data structure that will tell, in O(1) time, if an item exists in the set. Call this `kSet`. Complexity: O(k).

What you have now is a set that contains the item numbers you want, and a binary heap that has the the `k` smallest values in the array. Then:

```
i = 0;
while (!kSmallest.isEmpty())
{
    ++i;
    item = kSmallest.pop()  // O(log r)
    if (R.Contains(i))      // O(1)
    {
        output item
    }
}
```

The loop is O(r log r).

So the total complexity is O(k) + O(s) + O(r) + O(k) + O(r log r), which is the same order of O(s log r), because `r <= s`.

An alternative to step 2 is to use a min-heap selection algorithm, which would be O(s log r). That would save you having to include step 3, but it wouldn't improve the complexity.